# Unable to restore database to Amazon RDS target, unable to create a user with sufficient privileges

Tags: mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

This is the redacted output from Data Import/Restore in MySQL Workbench 5.2.47

```
23:16:23 Restoring H:\Clients\XX\XX\XX.sql

Running: mysql.exe --defaults-extra-file="c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\temp\tmphzm1qg.cnf"  --host=myrds.host.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --user=wordpress --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments --database=bitnami_wodpress < "H:\\Clients\\XX\\XX\\XX.sql"

ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 338: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation


Operation failed with exitcode 1
```

I can't give the only user I was able to create with MySQL workbench super privileges and I already modified the DB parameters on the RD, " (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)"

How do you get an SSH shell to the MySQL server that is running, or how do you get root access to the RDS or a super user.

It's kind of ridiculous. All I want is to import a database.

Comment: So what is the import trying to do at line 1227? I'm betting it will be trying to perform an operation related to stored procedures you may be able to ignore. If so you can add the '-f' option to the Mysql command to ignore those errors and process the rest of the file.

Comment: You can't get SUPER privileges on RDS. This is rarely a problem, but if you absolutely must have it then RDS is not for you and you'll need to build and run your own server.

Answer (score 0):

RDS doesn't allow SUPER user access.  The error about 'log_bin_trust_function_creators' happens to me when attempting to create routines, which needs to have the parameter changed, and the RDS instance rebooted.